# ¿Por qué no puedo ver los controles de mi Activity Xamarin Android?

Tags: xamarin.android

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Disculpen, soy nuevo en la parte Xamarin Android, tengo 2 layout: Main y Graficas, no entiendo porque en el segundo layout de Graficas me están apareciendo los controles del primer layout (Main), siendo que en segundo layout (Graficas) apenas agregue un botón, y éste no aparece.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La razon por la que se ven los objetos es porque el archivo de Resource (R en el caso de Java) es unico, indistinto de los layout que se tengan ya que estos son un recurso mas del archivo, y para que hacer que se vean nuevos elementos debe hacerse una compilacion, con el fin que se actualize el archivo R o en el caso de xamarin, el archivo resource

Comment: Vale, muchas gracias, si funcionó la recompilación, ahora ya me salieron los controles del layout 2 también.